# Are there any extant communities that would not eat meat from the hindquarters, even expertly porged?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, meat

There is a prohibition to eat from the sciatic nerve of an animal (*gid hanasheh*) as well as certain fats from a domesticated animal (*cheilev*). Before meat can be eaten, these must be removed via a process called *nikkur* (Hebrew) / *treibering* (Yiddish) / porging (English). See e.g. [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23312/what-is-kosher-meat/23313#23313) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47791/are-we-not-supposed-to-eat-fat/47792#47792).

As this process is time-consuming and difficult, in most Ashkenazic communities (at least outside of Israel) the entire hindquarters of the animal are instead sold to the non-kosher market.

Despite the relatively widespread belief that Ashkenazic Jews may never eat hindquarter meat, it would seem that the mainstream opinion is that they are in fact permitted to, if the *nikkur* has been performed by an expert as required. See e.g. [this article](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_nikkur_achoraim/) by R. Dr. Ari Zivotofsky.

However, as noted in that article:

> The practice of some communities to refrain from eating hindquarters, owing to the difficulty in excising the forbidden sections, continues to exist among both Ashkenazim and Sephardim.

My question is, are there communities out there today where this practice has the status of a full-fledged *minhag hamakom* (local custom) such that they would always forbid hindquarter meat, even where the *nikkur* was correctly carried out by an expert?

One source that I am aware of is R. Moshe Sternbuch, writing in [Teshuvot v'Hanhagot vol. 1, Yoreh De'ah 418](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=296) about what he believes to be the practice in Johannesburg, South Africa (*translation mine*):

> For us in our place [Johannesburg] this is a custom that is a 'fence' to avoid transgressing a prohibition and which cannot be annulled ... as fences such as these are a wall for the religion, and the Jewish people's keeping of the Torah depends on upholding the restrictions and fences that our fathers have been accustomed to from generation to generation, or the local custom, as it is the obligation of every rabbi to enact restrictions in his city and to enact according to what is necessary, and we are obligated to uphold the custom.

Are there any other sources ruling similarly in other current Jewish communities?

Comment: From the article by Rabbi Zivotofsky you linked, it sounds like London enacted a ban in the 20th century.

Comment: @Loewian Indeed. That seems like a promising angle to research...

Comment: According to this site https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/561078/jewish/Why-cant-I-find-kosher-filet-mignon.htm at least some cuts of meat from the hindquarters are available for sale

Answer (score 1):

From the article quoted below, taken from [HERE](http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=3090905&forum_id=16810) , it is very clear that it is an accepted minhag in ALL Ashkenazic communities. It is not just "out of lack of expertise or knowledge", but was accepted as a "full fledged minhag".

The writer points out that although in previous times some ashkenazic communities acted according to this minhag and some did not, it has become the universally accepted minhag among all ashkenazic communities not to eat the meat from the hindquarters of the animal.

The writer quotes R' Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe YD 2:42) saying that if a specific Shochet feels competent enough to remove all the forbidden parts, we cannot stop him from doing so. He expresses wonder that R' MF rules contrary to all the other sources quoted.

> עי' שו"ע (יו"ד סי' סד ס"ז) בדברי הרמ"א, ובכל הסימן שם, ומשום שניקור
>   האחוריים הוא מאד חמור וצריך קבלה גמורה וידיעה גדולה, הנהיג המהרש"ל שלא
>   לאכול בשר אחוריים, [עי' בבאר היטב (יו"ד שם סק"ז) שהביא דבר זה בסתם שיש
>   שהחמירו שלא לאכול בשר אחוריים], ובבית לחם יהודה (יו"ד סי' סד סק"ה)
>   ובישועות יעקב (שם) הביאו זאת בשם המהרש"ל, [עי' יש"ש חולין פ"א סי' ב,
>   ופ"ז סי' טו], וראה בערוך השלחן (יו"ד סי' סד סעיף נד), ואם כי בזמן
>   הקדום יותר היה חילוק במנהג המקומות בין האשכנזים עצמם [עיין בשו"ת חתם
>   סופר יו"ד סי' סח-סט, ובקובץ "ירושלים" שי"ל בוורשה שנת תרצו קובץ א עמ'
>   לד וקובץ ב' עמ' סא], אולם בדורות האחרונים התקינו בכל מקומות ישוב
>   האשכנזים, ובפרט כאן בארץ ישראל נהגו האשכנזים שלא לנקר מבשר אחוריים
>   כלל, ראה מה שכתב הדרכי תשובה (סי' סד ס"ק מו), ועי' שו"ת יד הלוי (לרי"ד
>   במברגר, יו"ד סי' ל) שכתב בתו"ד כי מה שאבותינו ואבות אבותינו נוחי נפש
>   הרבנים הגדולים שהיו בכל אלה המדינות שנהגו איסור לנקר האחוריים פשיטא
>   שלא משום טעות או חסרון ידיעה נהגו מנהגינו כן אלא שברוחב דעתם וגודל
>   ידיעתם בתלמוד תורה ועוז צדקתם בחנו וראו גודל המכשלה אשר תצא מזה אילו
>   נתיר לנקר האחוריים וכו' וע"כ נסוגו אחור לעשות סייג וגדר ומשמרת לאיסורי
>   תורה החמורים כי מאד קשה מלאכת הניקור וצריך אימון ובקיאות גדולה ושמוש
>   רב לדבר כנודע וכו' אשר על כן זה נכלל בסוג דבר שנהגו משום גדר ושידעו בו
>   שמותר והחמירו על עצמם כדת וכהלכה, ועי' שו"ת חבצלת השרון (ח"ב סי' כח),
>   ושו"ת תשוה"נ ח"א סי' תיח ותיט, ואמנם בזמן מלחמת העולם השניה שהיה נסיון
>   גדול ושעת הדחק גדול מאד היו מקומות שהקילו בזה עי' שו"ת אחיעזר (ח"ג סי'
>   פד) ושו"ת מקדשי השם (ח"א סי' כב ואילך), ובהגהות דבר צבי בשו"ת מקדשי
>   השם שהאריך בזה אך גם זה רק משום שהיה שעת הדחק גדול, ובפרט באותו זמן
>   שהיה חשש שאם לא יתנו לנקר אחוריים הדבר יגרום שלא יוכלו לקיים בכלל
>   שחיטה יהודית ראה שם נחשב כהתרה לצורך מצוה, ולכן הקילו בזה, ועי' שו"ת
>   אג"מ יו"ד ח"ב סי' מב (וצ"ע בדעתו מדברי כל הפוסקים שהבאנו לעיל). [אמנם
>   מה שיש חילוק בין הניקור הספרדי לניקור האשכנזי, לטענת נותני ההכשר
>   מקפידים אף על הניקור האשכנזי שהיה נהוג במקומות שנהגו לנקר ולאכול],
>   ואמנם בירושלים עד לפני כשישים שנה היו נוהגים האשכנזים להקל בחלקים
>   מסוימים לנקרם ולאוכלם ראה בספר "תורת הניקור הירושלמי", אולם כיום לא
>   נהגו לנקר, וגם בזה יש חילוק בין מנהג האשכנזים לספרדים ראה שם.

Comment: @JoelK It would seem? from what? where?...

Comment: An interesting item to note is that the verse says "Therefore **B'nai Yisra'el**" don't eat it. If the term "B'nai Yisrael" is considered "current" one could argue that Binyamin was exempt from this rule.

Comment: @JoelK In the article which I quoted it states "ועי' שו"ת אג"מ יו"ד ח"ב סי' מב (וצ"ע בדעתו מדברי כל הפוסקים שהבאנו לעיל)".

Comment: @JoelK but as the writer points out, this is contrary to all the other sources quoted. (not uncommon for R' Moshe F). I Edited it into the answer.

Comment: If R. Moshe disagrees, then I don't see how it can be claimed that this is an accepted minhag in all Ashkenazic communities. Presumably it's not a full-fledged custom among those that follow R. Moshe's rulings. So to answer my question fully, one would need to look up the sources quoted here (e.g. דרכי תשובה, יד הלוי) and work out which communities they were referring to when they discuss a full-fledged custom, and whether those communities can still be said to exist today.

Comment: In the article by R' Zivotofsky, linked to in the question, it appears that the communities that eat OU-certified venison, rely on nikur of the gid hanashe.

Comment: @Loewian See [these 2 articles](https://oukosher.org/search/?s=hindquarters) from the ou site which say that the minhag in America is to be machmir and the ou has accepted the minhag .

Comment: re the OU, the first article indeed claims that "due to the severity of the prohibition, some communities have adopted a custom of not using the hindquarters at all. This is the predominant custom in the USA, and it is followed by the OU." However, the second article is the one from R' Zivotofsky which instead notes that "the OU supervises nikkur of deer hindquarters in the United States, because in deer, only the gid hanasheh and blood require removal, but not the chailev." (I assume they distinguish between deer and domesticated animals.)